# Event listeners not working after animate a view - android titanium mobile?

Tags: android, animation, view, titanium, addeventlistener

I'm having a view containing 3 buttons added with click event listeners. After animate the view (changing top of the view), listeners are not working for those buttons under the view.
This is Working properly with iPhone, but not with android.How to fix this?

Comment: can you show your code.. it may possible need zindex property..:)

Comment: its working properly in iPhone, by setting top directly without animation working in android.. i guess the problem with animate. and callback method for animate also not working in android.. :(

Comment: I had this same problem.  Removing the animation from the android branch of code worked.  It's not as nice as the iOS animate, but it works and means not spending 2 days on it for no reason.